# insert row into PGSQL USING PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, prepared-statement

I cannot get php postgre to do an insert a row from a php array `new_address`, using this code:

```
    $customer_id = '2319';
    $use_frequency = 1;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("
    INSERT INTO address 
            ('storeid', 
             'classtypeid', 
             'modifiedbyuser', 
             'modifiedbycomputer', 
             'modifieddate', 
             'seqid', 
             'issystem', 
             'isactive', 
             'streetaddress1', 
             'streetaddress2', 
             'city', 
             'state', 
             'county', 
             'postalcode', 
             'country', 
             'formattedtext', 
             'taxclassid', 
             'isvalidated', 
             'validatedaddress', 
             'hasvalidationerror', 
             'validationerror', 
             'customer_id', 
             'use_frequency') 
   VALUES   ( NULL, 
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
             :address_1, 
             :address_2, 
             :city, 
             :state, 
              NULL, 
             :zip, 
             :country, 
             :formatted_text, 
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
             :customer_id, 
             :use_frequency");



$sth->execute(array(
    ':address_1' => $new_address['address_1'],
    ':address_2' => $new_address['address_2'],
    ':city' => $new_address['city'],
    ':state' => $new_address['state'],
    ':zip' => $new_address['zip'],
    ':country' =>$new_address['country'],
    ':formatted_text' => $formatted_text,
    ':customer_id' => $customer_id, 
    ':use_frequency' => $use_frequency
    );           


$sth->execute();
```

The last column in the table is `id` and it is a `serial` so I have omitted it, thinking it will auto-increment, but please tell me if I'm wrong.

I am getting the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "'storeid'" LINE 3: ('storeid', ^' in

`print_r($new_address);` shows me:

```
Array (
[0] => stdClass Object (
[customer_id] => 9319
)
[1] => stdClass Object (
[address_1] => 1515 example st
)
[2] => stdClass Object (
[address_2] => box 1
)
[3] => stdClass Object (
[city] => town
)
[4] => stdClass Object (
[state] => ST
)
[5] => stdClass Object (
[zip] => 12345
)
[6] => stdClass Object (
[country] => US
)
)
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [4.1. Lexical Structure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html), you must escape the column names with double quotes `"`

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of characters in double-quotes ("). A delimited identifier is always an identifier, never a key word. So "select" could be used to refer to a column or table named "select", whereas an unquoted select would be taken as a key word and would therefore provoke a parse error when used where a table or column name is expected.

```
INSERT INTO address 
        ("storeid", 
         "classtypeid", 
         ...
```

Additionally, if you set the default values for the columns to `NULL`, you can omit them from the  column list and use only those you really need

```
insert into address
    ("streetaddress1", 
     "streetaddress2", 
     "city", 
     "state", 
     ...)
values (:address_1, 
       :address_2, 
       :city, 
       :state, 
       ...)
```

From your comment, you must modify the `$new_address` array. It is indexed numerically and *not* by name.

If you can change the JSON to

```
{ "customer_id": 9319,
  "address_1": "1515 example trail",
  "address_2": "box 1",
  "city": "town city",
  "state": "MI",
  "zip": "12345",
  "country": "US" }
```

you can use

```
$new_address = json_decode($json, true);
```

to get an associative array.

If you cannot change the JSON, you must map it to an associative array

```
$json = json_decode('[ { "customer_id": 9319 }, { "address_1": "1515 example trail" }, { "address_2": "box 1" }, { "city": "town city" }, { "state": "MI" }, { "zip": "12345" }, { "country": "US" } ]');

foreach ($json as $element) {
    foreach ($element as $key => $val) {
        $new_address[$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have changed that. I now get the error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at end of input LINE 48: $9 ^'`

Comment: @thomas This would be the last line. Add a closing paranthesis `)` to your statement.

Comment: Aha. Great. I now (of course) get the following error: ` sequence address_id_seq1'`. Which is odd. because I don't have a column named `address_id_seq`. Is it maybe a problem with the last autoincrement `id` column?

Comment: @thomas I don't know. This depends on how you defined `sequence address_id_seq1` and `address`, of course.

Comment: I just never created anything called `address_id_seq1` is the thing. I used phpPgAdmin to set up the database and that particular table. Can I define the sequence afterward?

Comment: aha. got that permissions thing sorted. It appears however, that though the query successfully adding rows, the data isn't being bound to the query. All rows where I use the `:variable` syntax are being added to the table as `NULL` Any ideas? Thank for your input!

Comment: @thomas I just looked at [8.1.4. Serial Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) and from that, I would say it should just work. What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: No error now. It's adding rows to the table. But they're not populated with the values that are in my array. They're empty.

Comment: @thomas Your statement looks fine. Have you dumped the `$new_address` array to see, if the values are correct? The `print_r` in your question shows the names without the leading colon `:`.

Comment: this is how i'm getting the address data `$new_address = json_decode('[ { "customer_id": 9319 }, { "address_1": "1515 example trail" }, { "address_2": "box 1" }, { "city": "town city" }, { "state": "MI" }, { "zip": "12345" }, { "country": "US" } ]');`

Comment: that prints `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [customer_id] => 9319 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [address_1] => 1515 example trail ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [address_2] => box 1 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [city] => town city ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [state] => MI ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [zip] => 12345 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [country] => US ) )`

Comment: @thomas Now I got it. You have an array of objects and not an array indexed by `customer_id`, `address_1`, ... Please see updated answer.